# Datetime / Timespan order by hour

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects. Each object has a `DateTime` property.

When I'm adding objects, to this list the DateTime is instantiated through ParseExact.

```
public class Event
{
    public Event(string time)
    {
         Time = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

This allows me to add items like so:

```
Events.AddRange(new List<Event> { new Event("07:00 +" + timeZone), new Event("11:30 +" + timeZone), new Event("16:00 +" +timeZone), new Event("19:00 +" + timeZone), new Event("00:00 +" + timeZone), new Event("03:00 +" +timeZone) });
```

I'm using DateTime, because it handles the timezones in the background.

Problem is; I want to create a list that sorts the above list, with the current time.

so if the list had `["7:30", "5:12", "15:55", "22:22", "23:59"]` and the current time is 22:19, it would sort it from that time.
So it would be: `["22:22", "23:59", "5:12", "7:30", "15:55"]`

I already have a function that does that:

```
Events.Sort((x,y) => x.Time.TimeOfDay.CompareTo(y.Time.TimeOfDay));
```

Problem is that, it's all the same day (Today).

To illustrate with the list above (given the date and time is 25/7 22:19, it would be:

`["22:22 25/7", "23:59 25/7", "5:12 25/7", "7:30 25/7", "15:55 25/7"]`

I hope this illustrates my point, as the date should turn to the 26th, past midnight, and so on...

Another thing is, that it returns a list as long as the input length, but ideally this could go on forever (hope this makes sense). It would be nice to be able to ask for 10 items, and it will return the next 10 items, from the current time.

**Edit: Clarification**
I'm getting a list of DateTimes, only the hour and minute of the DateTime object is relevant. 
From this moment, I want to get the next 10, 25 or 50 DateTimes objects. This can be generated as the hours and minutes are the only relevant data in the datetime object. The items should then be ordered by now and so forth.

**Edit 2: Timezones**
In above code, timezone = "0000", UTC.
This will on the users end automatically convert the time to the users current location.

Comment: The code you've given wouldn't compile - did you mean `Time = DateTime.ParseExact(...);`?

Comment: My apologies, that was exactly what I meant :)

Comment: The rest of what you're trying to do really isn't clear to me, unfortunately - what do you mean by "as the date should turn to the 26th etc"? Do you mean you're trying to create the next 10 `DateTime` values starting from now, with times of day from the list? What do you mean by "time zone" here? I strongly suspect it may not be the same as mine. If you could make it clearer what you're really trying to achieve, I suspect there could be a much better way of achieving it. I don't think this is really about sorting at all.

Comment: I've updated my question, hope this makes more sense.

Comment: "I'm getting a list of DateTimes, only the hour and minute of the DateTime object is relevant." In that case, I suggest you don't store them as `DateTime` values at all. Within .NET types, `TimeSpan` is often used for time-of-day values - personally I don't like that, but `DateTime` isn't ideal either. (I'd use my Noda Time library and `LocalTime`, but that's a different matter.) Will think about the simplest way of achieving this...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks! This can maybe give you a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve. https://d3b4yo2b5lbfy.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/0e65eWorld-Event-Times-EN-6-17-2014.pdf This is my data, I just need a list of upcoming events. DateTime takes care of the TimeZone different, making it quite convenient ^^

Comment: I personally wouldn't want to use the `DateTime` handling of time zones, particularly around DST changes... and we still don't know what you're actually *doing* with time zones. If you could clarify this, it would help me give a working solution (based on Noda Time, as I think that'll be the cleanest way of doing it - you can convert it to `DateTime` if you really want to later). In particular, are the times of day meant to be local? What do you want to happen if a time of day ends up being ambiguous or skipped due to a DST change?

Comment: Updated my post, and I've updated my post again ^^

Comment: So it's not actually a time zone, but a UTC offset? What happens when the client changes UTC offset, e.g. due to a DST change? (That's the difference - in a real time zone, the UTC offset typically changes over time.)

Comment: If it was me, I would convert it to timestamp and divide all minute out, then sort it.

Comment: @JonSkeet exactly, I'm sorry that was unclear. I was counting on DateTime handling that :I

Comment: @Jazerix: That doesn't explain how you expect it to behave - and I really wouldn't just assume it'll do what you want if you haven't thought through *exactly* how you want it to behave. Time zones are tricky, and `DateTime` is a far from ideal type when it comes to them - particularly in terms of the lack of control given. If you give details on *exactly* how you want things to be handled, it should be fairly easy to code that up... but you need to think about that first. (With date and time work, usually the coding isn't the hard part - it's working out what you want.)

Comment: All I can say, is that it have bahaved like it should on my side. If you take a look at the pdf doc i linked earlier, all I really want is to get a list of upcoming events. Each event is listed as UTC (US Pacific Time, US Eastern Time, Central European
Time), UTC being the only relevant one. When I load the Event times into my program, I load them as UTC, when I boot up the app on my end, and it takes the time difference into account, and gives me the time of event, in my timezone (CET) :)

Comment: @JonSkeet would you kindly take a look at the answer I provided?

Comment: Sorry, but without more detailed requirements I think it would be a waste of my time. Converting UTC values into local time is easy, but the other way round is where you can have ambiguity. Suppose your `List<Event>`  has "01:30" in it, but that time of day is skipped, or occurs twice - how are you going to handle that? Just because your code works in non-corner-case situations doesn't mean it will work in all cases.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from. This is merely meant to be a small app. Having to put more time in the timezones differences than the app itself, just seems like a bad allocation of time :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it like this. Following @JonSkeet, I switched to a TimeSpan object istead of a DateTime.

```
public List<Event> Events = new List<Event>();

public void InitializeTimers()
{
    Boss tequalt = new Boss("Tequatl the Sunless", BossPriority.HardCore) { Location = "Splintered Coast", Image = "tequatl.jpg" };
    Events.AddRange(new List<Event>
    {
        new Event("07:00", tequalt),
        new Event("11:30", tequalt)
    });
}

public List<Event> GetEvents(int count)
{
    InitializeTimers();
    var timeSpanPattern = Events.OrderBy(x => x.Time.Hours).ThenBy(x => x.Time.Hours);
    var newOrder = new List<Event>();
    var previousTimes = new List<Event>();
    foreach (var timespan in timeSpanPattern)
    {
        if (timespan.Time.CompareTo(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay) != -1)
            newOrder.Add(timespan);
        else
            previousTimes.Add(timespan);
    }
    newOrder.AddRange(previousTimes);
    var finalList = new List<Event>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int extraDays = i / (newOrder.Count);
        int current = i - (extraDays * newOrder.Count);
        if (newOrder[current].Time.CompareTo(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay) != 1)
            extraDays++;
        DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(newOrder[current].Time.Hours + ":" + newOrder[current].Time.Minutes + " +0000", "H:m zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddDays(extraDays);
        var newEvent = new Event { Boss = newOrder[current].Boss, DateAndTime = time, Time = newOrder[current].Time};
        newEvent.CalculateCountdown();
        finalList.Add(newEvent);
    }
    finalList.Sort((x,y) => x.DateAndTime.CompareTo(y.DateAndTime));
    return finalList;
}
```

Given `GetEvents(10)` (date is 27-7-2015 and time is 11:00), it will return

```
[0] = Event.DateAndTime = "27-7-2015 11:30";
[1] = Event.DateAndTime = "28-7-2015 7:00";
[2] = Event.DateAndTime = "28-7-2015 11:30";
[3] = Event.DateAndTime = "29-7-2015 7:00";
[4] = Event.DateAndTime = "29-7-2015 11:30";
[5] = Event.DateAndTime = "30-7-2015 7:00";
[6] = Event.DateAndTime = "30-7-2015 11:30";
[7] = Event.DateAndTime = "31-7-2015 7:00";
[8] = Event.DateAndTime = "31-7-2015 11:30";
[9] = Event.DateAndTime = "1-8-2015 7:00";
```

It isn't pretty at all, but it get's the job done, and allows me to specify how many items I want.

If anybody knows how to optimize above, I will gladly accept it as the answer.

Comment: Aside from anything else, there's no need to do all that string parsing in the middle. Get the date, then add the timespan to it...

Answer (score 0):

You can add 1 day to the dates if they're before the start dates:

```
Events.Sort((x, y) =>
{
    var xTime = x.Time;
    var yTime = y.Time;
    if (xTime < startTime)
        xTime = xTime.AddDays(1);
    if (yTime < startTime)
        yTime = yTime.AddDays(1);

    return xTime.CompareTo(yTime);
});
```

Note that I compared the dates, not the `TimeOfDay`, since the dates no longer have the same day.

This gives the expected result:

Before sort:

```
25/07/2015 07:30:00 
25/07/2015 05:12:00 
25/07/2015 15:55:00 
25/07/2015 22:22:00 
25/07/2015 23:59:00
```

After sort:

```
25/07/2015 22:22:00 
25/07/2015 23:59:00 
25/07/2015 05:12:00 
25/07/2015 07:30:00 
25/07/2015 15:55:00
```

Comment: After midnight should be 26 though, but it seems to be working like so on my end ^^ Thanks for the effort! Unfortunately this doesn't give me the option of keep on generating events, if that makes sense :)

Comment: @Jazerix, "After midnight should be 26 though": the date displayed is the one from the event, which is not modified by the sort function. The date part in the event is meaningless, since you only want to store the time. But perhaps you should store the full date in the event, it would make it easier to sort.